# json format cast to varchar

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I write the query in postgresql I have store the data in json format of one column and now I need the particular value of the json

message_data :`{"apiMessageId":"162fbbbe8f0e2a67","userEmail":"jack@liveonlinecloud.info","cloudId":1}`

This is data and I want to only userEmail
and this is my query

```
SELECT id, process_id, process_state, cast(message_data->> \'userEmail\' AS VARCHAR) AS userEmail, inserted_at, completed_at 
FROM realtimeincomingemailnotificationsqueue 
where api_message_id = '162fbbbe8f0e2a67';
```

Comment: `cast(message_data->> 'userEmail')::varchar`, but it is `text` anyway, so I dont see any need in additional cast

Comment: The backslash does not escape anything in SQL. You should use `'userEmail'` rather than `\'userEmail\'`

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

> ->>   text    Get JSON object field as **text**

(emphasis mine)

so I don't why you would want to cast `text` to `varchar`, but if you really do, use

```
cast(message_data->> 'userEmail')::varchar
```